# Simultaneous HDMI and Analog output stopped working (raspbmc)

Tags: raspbmc, audio, hdmi

I had audio being output to both HDMI and Analog outputs perfectly... Now I can only select one output or the other, but not both at the same time.

Unfortunately I have no idea what I did or when this issue started.. Maybe this is something that the July update broke?

Any suggestions to help debug this would be welcome.

Comment: Can you get other programs to output to both? (i.e. is this a raspbmc issue, or an underlying system one?)

Comment: I was looking for this feature as well, but since i missed the june update, i thought it was me.
Seemed like an ideal solution for operation without having to turn on the tv. Hope the august built will fix this, since Raspbmc is getting really, really good!

Comment: Not sure how to go about checking this. I did confirm it doesn't work in a fresh install of raspbmc though - so it's not just some config I messed up. Any ideas how to roll back to the previous June release?

Comment: I've got the same situation here. Simultanious digital and analoge sound output worked perfectly until august. After my return from holidays, the function in the menu was gone. I tried reinstalling an older version of Raspbmc, but that didn't work.

Comment: I thought it was not possible to use both at the same time? At all, ever. This is a surprise.

Comment: It seems dual audio is gone again with 13.1 Beta2 (or already in versions before).

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in the [August](http://www.raspbmc.com/2013/08/raspbmcs-august-update/) update, along with many more fixes and enhancements:

> Re-added support for Dual Audio (simultaneous analog and HDMI output)